# Posting href link in server side processing table using Url.Action in controller using c#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I want to add a href row into my server side processing table from controller.

```
JQArray dRow = new JQArray();
dRow.Add("<a target=\"_blank\" href='@Url.Action(\"myAction\", \"myController\", new { @Id = RecViewModel.Id })'> "+ RecordViewModel.Name+" </a>");
```

The name is shown successfully but when I click the name to open the link, the resource cannot be found and the navigation link shows:

```
http://localhost:1121/@Url.Action(%myAction%22,%20%myController%22,%20new%20%7B%20@Id%20=%20RecViewModel.Id%20%7D)
```

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /@Url.Action("myAction", "myController", new { @Id = RecViewModel.Id })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to put `Url.Action` in single quote.

try this -

```
JQArray dRow = new JQArray();
dRow.Add("<a target=\"_blank\" href='" + Url.Action("myAction", "myController", new { @Id = RecViewModel.Id }) + "'>"+ RecordViewModel.Name+" </a>");
```

Comment: Hi @Krishnraj, what if I want to have another hyperlink at the same row? How to separate two JToken?